# Magento redirect to homepage after changing base url to www?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.8

My old base url was http://mensstore.biz/ . I changed it to http://www.mensstore.biz/ .
But when I access my inner pages like /generics.html with old url without www,it redirects to home page. I want if user enter www or without www it must remain on the same page.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can issue for htaccess.

Step1:find htacess `RewriteEngine on` the added below for Redirecting `non-www to www url`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mensstore\.biz
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mensstore.biz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Step 2:`Goto` your database  and then go to `core_config_data` there search

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%secure/base_url%'
```

run the query and if you find any record  have `http://mensstore.biz/` then change `http://www.mensstore.biz/`

and
`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%secure/base_link%"`
run the query and if you find any record  have `http://mensstore.biz/` then change `http://www.mensstore.biz/`

Comment: Thanks Amit, but it didn't help

Comment: please clear and session from yourmagento dir/var/cache or yourmagento dir/var/session